# Unable to update database table from php page

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update whatever content in the textbox that has been edited and post to database. However, only the second record is update but the first record is not. I think should be the while loop problem but I don't what is the mistake.
Here's my edit page code:
viewadmindb.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('adminconfig.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin ORDER BY ID"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
?>


<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="status"></div>
<form method="POST" action="adminsave.php" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
<table class="viewdb"  contentEditable="true">
<tr><td id='fcolor' style='border:2px solid black' align=center> ID </td>
<td id='fcolor' style='border:2px solid black' align=center> Name </td>
<td id='fcolor' style='border:2px solid black' align=center> Password </td>
<td id='fcolor' style='border:2px solid black; width:auto;' align=center>           
 Department</td>
<td id='fcolor' style='border:2px solid black' align=center> Email </td></tr>
<div id="content">
<?php

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<tr>
      <td style='border:2px solid black; width:auto' align=center><?php echo $row[] = 
      $row['ID'] ?></td>
 <td style='border:2px solid black' align=center> <?php echo $row[]    
     = $row['name']  ?> </td>
<td style='border:2px solid black' align=center> <?php echo $row[] =    
    $row['password']  ?> </td>
<td style='border:2px solid black; width:200px' align=center> <?php echo $row[] =
    $row['department'] ?> </td>
<td style='border:2px solid black' align=center> <?php echo $row[] = $row['email']
    ?> </td>

<tr>
    <td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="ID[]" value='<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>' 
     maxlength="50"></td>

    <td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="name[]" value='<?php echo $row['name']  
      ?>' 
     maxlength="50"></td>
     <td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="password[]" value='<?php echo  
     $row['password'] ?>' maxlength=50"></td>

     <td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="department[]" value='<?php echo   
     $row['department'] ?>' maxlength="50"></td>

    <td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="email[]" value='<?php echo 
     $row['email']?>' 
     style='width:300px' " maxlength="50"></td>

    <?php } ?>
   <td><input id='edit' type='submit' name='<?php $row['ID'] ?>' value='Submit'/> 
    </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
    <?php 
    $ID=$row['ID'];
$name=$row['name'];
$password=$row['password'];
$department=$row['department'];
$email=$row['email'];
?>
```

adminsave.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('adminconfig.php');

$ids=$_POST['ID'];
$name_arr=$_POST['name'];
$password_arr=$_POST['password'];
$department_arr=$_POST['department'];
$email_arr=$_POST['email'];

foreach(($ids as $key=>$id) {
     $name = $name_arr[$key];
     $password = $password_arr[$key];
     $department = $department_arr[$key];
     $email = $email_arr[$key];       
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET name = '$name',password = '$password',
department ='$department',email = '$email' WHERE ID = '$id'";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){
   die('invalid query:'.mysql_error());
 }
else
echo ("<tr><td>" . "Data updated succesfully..." . "</td></tr>");
header('Refresh:5; url=viewadmindb.php');
die;

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean as second record

Comment: There is no loop in adminsave.php, that needs to loop through all the inputs to store those multiple records.

Comment: I just glanced through the code, and I notice that it is vulnerable to SQL injections. It is probably a bad idea to put this on SO, in case anyone gets the idea of copying it.. (You're dumping the contents of $_POST variables into your query w/o sanitizing it)

Comment: Right nw my database only contain 2 records,in the textbox, it displays 2 records as well as i implemented, the 2nd record i edited can be save to database but not the 1st record

Comment: Can you show me how the loop works?

Answer (score 1):

You really should look up into how ID's are supposed to work in html. The basic things is that ID must be unique. You should not have two or more elements with same ID. But in your case it's the name-attribute that is the issue.

*If you have a loop like this..*.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<tr>
<td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="ID" value='<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>' 
 maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>
```

}?>

*...and you have two rows from the $result-recordset*, you will echo out html something like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="ID" value='1' 
 maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="ID" value='2' 
 maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>
```

Your then saving values into the database based on a element with name ID. But the problem is that PHP doesn't know which of the rows above it should use (How could PHP know?). When refering to an element that has a duplicate the last element in the DOM is used. Therefore only this row is take into account:

```
<tr>
<td><input id='edit' type = 'text' name="ID" value='2' 
 maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>
```

*There are no loop in adminsave.php that indicates you want to save several values*. It just tells that you want to save content into database with a specific ID.

```
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET name = '$name',password = '$password',
department ='$department',email = '$email' WHERE ID = '$ID'";
```

and because the last row in the DOM is used, the update-statement would be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE admin SET name = '$name',password = '$password',
department ='$department',email = '$email' WHERE ID = '2'";
```

You can solve this by making the name-element an array by adding brackets to name-elements: (Also make edit a class instead of an id because it's ok to have duplicate classes but not duplicate ids)

```
<tr>
<td><input class='edit' type = 'text' name="ID[]" value='<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>' 
 maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>
```

But then you would also have to loop through the array

```
<?php
$ids = $_POST['ID']; //Get array from form
$name_arr = $_POST['name'];
$password_arr = $_POST['password'];
$department_arr = $_POST['department'];
$email_arr = $_POST['email'];

foreach($ids as $key=>$id) {
    //Get specific element in each array
    $name = $name_arr[$key]; 
    $password = $password_arr[$key];
    $department = $department_arr[$key];
    $email = $email_arr[$key];

    //Create sql and execute
    $sql = "UPDATE admin SET name = '$name',password = '$password',
    department ='$department',email = '$email' WHERE ID = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

The row:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE $ID = '$ID'";
```

is pointless because the variable $sql is overritten on the next row.

Note that above is just for demonstrating how the basic concepts of ids, names and arrays works when handling forms. You should really not just mysql_* functions, but instead read up on PDO or mysqli instead. You should sanitize (make sure unwanted data is not injected into db) before updating.

Comment: Ok, i got it, it seems the loop is working but it gives me the error 
Array to string conversion
And now all the database content only display "Array" instead of the previous data.

Comment: @user2655507 - please update your code in your question and send a message when that's done - I will took a look at it.

Comment: @user2655507 - you have to put the posted arrays inside of the loop (beside $_POST['ID']). I'll update my answer.

Comment: omg, i cant believe it work, thanks to you! u sure is the bestprogrammerintheworld!

Comment: @user2655507 - hehe really I'm not, but I'm glad to help! :-)

Comment: @user2655507 - accept this as answer if you think it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

The whole Logic is wrong.

1. Just pass in the query string from main page to another php page ex from:admin_detail.php to edit_admin.php
2. Then query db for data based on passed query string
3. echo them in desired textbox.
4. then call update statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to php.

1. Your code is not well formated and not really readable.
2. Don't do $_POST['...'] and write this value directly into database (security issue => mysql injection) So please insert mysql_real_escape_string($value) before you insert into database.
3. What the hack is that? **echo $row[] = $row['password']** don't do that! only echo is enough.

**Solution of your answer:**
It's normal that your code update only the last iteration of the while loop, because only the last value will be stored into the $_POST array.
If you wanna fix that you have to make the form as array like:

```
<input id='edit' type = 'text' name="name[]" value='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>' 
 maxlength="50">
```

Then in your viewadmindb.php you have to iterate over this values again and make for each value an extra update query which updates the value in the database.

**UPDATE:**

The foreach loop should look like this in adminsave.php:

```
$arrIds = array();
$arrNames = array();
$arrDepartments = array();
$arrPasswords = array();
// ... add all necessary vars you wan a fetch from the post request
$arrIds[] = $_POST['name'][];
$arrNames[] = $_POST['name'][];
$arrDepartments[] = $_POST['department'][];

$arrResults = array();   // To store result data if necessary 
foreach($arrIds as $key => $item) {
  // Build sql query
  $sql = "UPDATE admin SET name = '". $arrNames[$key] . "',password = '". $arrPasswords[$key] . "',
  department ='". $arrDepartments[$key] . "',email = '". $arrEmailss[$key] . "' WHERE ID = '$item'";
  // Execute query!
  $arrResults[] = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

So now you should be able to get it running...

Comment: <input id='edit' type = 'text' name="name[]" value='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>' 
 maxlength="50">
but this only insert the "name‘ value when the submit button is clicked, how about the rest variable? Can i just update all data by clicking 1 button and all edited data wil be update to database?

Comment: Yes right. You send an array of data to the other php script. So if you call in the other script which handles the post data something like: var_dump($_POST['name'][]) you'll get all names.  You have to do that with all variables. 
And yes you can update all data because you iterating over all values in the script which should update the database (executing the query).

I'm not here to write the hole code... Some brainpower has to come from the programmer itself :) .

Answer (score 0):

**viewadmindb.php**

The var `$row` you didnot set. Just ad this `$row = mysql_fetch_array($reslult);` before you access to table values.

What is this `$row[] = $row['name']` ? You refill `$row`, and after you cannot access the original value from database. Use ony labels, no vars like `<td> E-mail: </td>`

**adminsave.php**
You rewrited the $sql var. The line `$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE $ID = '$ID';` you donot need to use.

Good tip: use the css syntax `` ` `` and border the varchars with `{$var}`:

```
"UPDATE `admin` SET `name` = '{$name}', `password` = '{$password}', `department` = '{$department}', `email` = '{$email}' WHERE `ID` = '{$ID}'"
```